# React, Se puede invocar dos reducers en un mismo archivo? Error 'dispatch' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un reducer (shopReduder.js) que maneja el filtrado de los articulos.
Tengo otro reducer (carritoReducer.js) que maneja el añadir o quitar carritos del carro.

En el archivo shopScreen.js estoy invocando esos dos reducers:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(shopReducer, articulos);
const [carro, dispatch] = useReducer(carritoReducer, []);
```

Pero salta el siguiente error:

```
./src/components/ShopScreen.js
SyntaxError: D:\Cursos\REACT1\tienda-react\src\components\ShopScreen.js: Identifier 
'dispatch' has already been declared. (18:18)

16 |    //Reducer
17 |     const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(shopReducer, articulos);
> 18 |     const [carro, dispatch] = useReducer(carritoReducer, []);
 |                   ^
```

Lo que me lleva a pensar que no se pueden invocar dos reducers en un mismo archivo. Es esto así? o que puede estar pasando? Disculpad pero soy nueva en React.

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que esta declarando la variable dispatch 2 veces y efectivamente lo haces:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(shopReducer, articulos);
                ^ aqui
const [carro, dispatch] = useReducer(carritoReducer, []);
                ^ y otra vez aqui
```

Tendras que renombrar una de ellas para que no te salga el error o asignar nombre diferentes a ambas:

```
const [state, shopDispatch] = useReducer(shopReducer, articulos);
const [carro, carroDispatch] = useReducer(carritoReducer, []);
```